# Why doesn't a post-increment/decrement operator have any effect on a variable inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword, post-increment

```
var j = 0;
for( var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    j = j++;
    console.log(j);
}
```

The output of the above block of code is 100 zeros instead of numbers from 1 to 100?

```
j = j + 1;
```

The above code on the other hand works as expected.
What might be the reason behind this?

Comment: `j++` is **POST**-increment. your `j=j++` is basically `temp = j; j++; j = temp`.

Comment: Java **IS NOT** JavaScript.

Comment: You don't need the assignment operator.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Was searching for **JAVA** in this. Good that you edited. Thanks

Comment: I recommend to read the [**documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_(.2B.2B))

Comment: I don't have the privs to do a 1-character edit, but the word in the title should be 'effect'

Comment: @rdb Sorry for the silly typo.

Comment: int j = 0; j < 100 ? console.log(j++) : ;

Comment: Or ++j of you actually want to see 1 - 100

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`j++` loads the current value of `j`, then increments the variable, then returns the original value.

`j = j++` reassigns the original value of `j`, which is 0, back to `j` with every iteration of the loop.

If you just put `j++;` on a line by itself inside the loop you'll see that it does increment.

Comment: if j++ returns the current value of j and then increments it, then why does the value remain the same? shouldn't it be incremented by 1  with each iteration?

Comment: @chaosifier The operations in `j = j++;` are 1. return current value of j (0), 2. Increment j. 3. Assign return value to j. In that order. After 2 j is incremented, but you set it back to 0 in step 3. Edited my answer to try and make that a little more clear.

Comment: Ahh, I'd always thought `j++` was just shorthand for `j = j +1` - I can't think why you'd do `j = j++` but I would've thought if `j = 7` then `m = j++` (for example) would assign 8 to both `j` and `m`. This answer seems woefully underappreciated in its ability to explain the difference

Answer (score 2):

Because it's a post-increment and not a pre-increment. The value of `j` is first assigned the value zero, *then* incremented to the new value, which is wasted in the next iteration.

`j = j++` translates to:

1. Load the value of `j`, which is zero.
2. Increment `j`.
3. Store the loaded value in step 1 to `j`. Note that the increment in step 2 is lost because its *old value* was loaded in step 1.

`j = ++j` translates to:

1. Increment `j`.
2. Load the value of `j` which is incremented.
3. Store the loaded value back to `j`.

Answer (score 1):

You are post incrementing j.At `j = j++` value is of `j = 0` and it remains 0 as `j++` will increment the value after the execution of the statement.You can have just `console.log(++j);` in for loop.